# How to make an Jquery Ajax call with Json data as parameter?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an ajax call to Action in ASP.NET MVC framework. In Action string jsonModel is always getting as null. What I missing here? Can you please help?

FYI -- I'm trying to keep the signature of the Action same as I'm using an existing action. It would be great if we could check the way we are sending Json data to Action and why following action is failing to get the Json string.

Ajax Call :

```
function send(SubmissionID, EntityOrganizationID) {
    var user = $('#commentrecipients').val();
    var comment = $('#Comment').val();  

    var scObj = {};
    scObj["EntityOrganizationID"] = EntityOrganizationID;
    scObj["SubmissionID"] = SubmissionID;
    scObj["Comment"] = comment;
    scObj["RecipientModels"] = user;

    
    var jsonModel = JSON.stringify(scObj);
    alert(jsonModel);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Submission/SubmissionHeaderCommentAction",
        dataType: "JSON", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
        data: jsonModel,
        async:false,
        success: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request succeeded
            options.success(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request failed
            options.error(result);
        }
    });
```

Action:

```
[AuditItem("SubmissionHeaderCommentAction")]
        public ActionResult SubmissionHeaderCommentAction(string jsonModel) // jsonModel comes as null
        {
            //convert json to our poco model
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonModel);
.........

  return AdComplianceStatusResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Comment submitted successfully");
        }
```

Comment: This post needs more details and clarity

Comment: added more info. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. Added the  code that you wanted. It is tested and working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix your ajax

```
function send(SubmissionID, EntityOrganizationID) {
    var user = $('#commentrecipients').val();
    var comment = $('#Comment').val();  

    var jsonModel= 
    {
      entityOrganizationID: EntityOrganizationID,
    submissionID : SubmissionID,
    comment : comment,
   recipientModels = user
};
    $.ajax({
       url: "/Submission/SubmissionHeaderCommentAction",
         data: {jsonModel},
         success: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request succeeded
            options.success(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request failed
            options.error(result);
        }
    });
```

IMHO  much better way to use viewModel

```
public CommentViewModel
{
public int EntityOrganizationID {get; set;}, 
public int SubmissionID {get; set;}, 
public string Comment {get; set;}, 
public string  RecipientModels {get; set;}
}
```

with this action

```
public IActionResult SubmissionHeaderCommentAction(CommentViewModel viewModel )
    {

     //do something with data
    
      return Ok("Comment submitted successfully");
    }
```

UPDATE

If you need to use existing action you can use this code ( it was tested in Visual Studio)

```
public IActionResult SubmissionHeaderCommentAction(string jsonModel)
    {

CommentViewModel result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommentViewModel>(jsonModel);
    
     ....your code
    }
```

and use this ajax

```
function send(SubmissionID, EntityOrganizationID) {
    var user = $('#commentrecipients').val();
    var comment = $('#Comment').val();  

    var jsonObj= 
    {
      entityOrganizationID: EntityOrganizationID,
    submissionID : SubmissionID,
    comment : comment,
   recipientModels = user
  };
var jsonModel= = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

    $.ajax({
       url: "/Submission/SubmissionHeaderCommentAction",
         data: { JsonModel:jsonModel },
         success: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request succeeded
            options.success(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request failed
            options.error(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach works well for me. But the action I'm using is an existing one. I've a choice to reuse it or duplicate same code and write a new action, next break it down to individual paraments and pass them as ajax data like you suggested. I was wondering is there any way we could keep existing action with same signature and reuse it.

Comment: I finally thought to make this as a separate Action as I had to put more logic inside. Your approach really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Bull's eye! I love that data: { JsonModel:jsonModel }. It was bit tricky. Thank you very much for your help. Great Job.

Comment: Hi Sergey - I think you are one of the best here in Ajax and MVC. I posted another issue. If you get a chance can you please take a look at it and see if you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67340550/how-to-display-kendodropdownlist-by-calling-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/67340733#67340733

Comment: @Partha thank you, but I never worked with kendo. Did you think about using a common net select  list for your application instead of a kendo one?

Comment: This is probably nothing to do with Kendo. I've updated the code and description. When I'm binding in Action - It works with sample test data and drop down populates but when I try this with real data - mostly parsing it's not working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67340550/how-to-display-kendodropdownlist-by-calling-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/67340733#67340733

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
 var jsonModel = JSON.stringify(scObj);

  var newObj = {data:jsonModel };//<===========  
  var newJsonModel  = JSON.stringify(newObj);//<===========

$.ajax({
            url: "/Submission/SubmissionHeaderCommentAction",
            dataType: "application/json",  //<=========
            data: newJsonModel ,//<===========
            async:false,
            success: function (result) {
                // notify the data source that the request succeeded
                options.success(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                // notify the data source that the request failed
                options.error(result);
            }
        });
```

Action:

```
[AuditItem("SubmissionHeaderCommentAction")]
        public ActionResult SubmissionHeaderCommentAction([FromBody]string data ) //<==============
        {
            //convert json to our yourPocoModel
           dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(data); 

  return AdComplianceStatusResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Comment submitted successfully");
        }
```

*** Uodated

Comment: That's an existing Action in my codebase. No way to keep the parameter type same in action and make it work? Otherwise I've to write an action again. In that case I could break it down to individual paraments and pass it int/string to Action.

Comment: Same issue persists. We have to keep the same signature of Action. If I break it down into individual parameters and pass to Action it works. Only issue with this approach is that we have to write another action and keep the existing one aside. This one works -- public ActionResult SubmissionHeaderCommentActionNew(int SubmissionID, int? EntityOrganizationID, string Comment, int UserID){....}       data: {
            SubmissionID: SubmissionID,
            EntityOrganizationID: EntityOrganizationID,
            Comment: Comment,
            UserID: UserID
        },

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your concept to make things easier:

```
function send(SubmissionID, EntityOrganizationID) {
    var user = $('#commentrecipients').val();
    var comment = $('#Comment').val();  

    var scObj = new Object();
    scObj.entityOrganizationID = EntityOrganizationID;
    scObj.submissionID = SubmissionID;
    scObj.comment = comment;
    scObj.recipientModels = user;

    
    var jsonModel = JSON.stringify(scObj);
    alert(jsonModel);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Submission/SubmissionHeaderCommentAction",
        dataType: "JSON", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
        data: jsonModel,
        async:false,
        success: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request succeeded
            options.success(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // notify the data source that the request failed
            options.error(result);
        }
    });
```

And simply return json:

```
public JsonResult SubmissionHeaderCommentAction(int entityOrganizationID, int submissionID, string comment, string  recipientModels)
    {
                //so something with data
    
      return Json("Comment submitted successfully", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: No way to keep the signature same. That action is an existing one. I don't wanted to duplicate the action code. But your approach works.