# How to display kendoDropDownList by calling ajax in ASP.NET MVC framework?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, action, kendo-dropdown

I've a Kendo kendoDropDownList. I'm trying to populate drop down values by calling Ajax. Unfortunately every time I click the drop down it calls the Action and it returns the values but dropdown does not display list. I tested several times with a simple Dictionary and it works fine with test data (Shown in code) but when I populate the same with real data it's not showing drop down values. Can you please take a look If I'm doing anything wrong?

Action:

```
public ActionResult SubmitterActionTypes(int id)
        {
            var types = ServiceProvider.SupplementalDataService.SubmitterActionTypes()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name);

   
            Dictionary<int, string> typesDic = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            // Following Test code works fine and drop down populates with values...
            /*typesDic.Add(1, "Item 1");
            typesDic.Add(2, "Item 2");
            typesDic.Add(3, "Item 3");
            typesDic.Add(4, "Item 4");*/

            // Following code does not work and dropdown does not show any result
            foreach(var type in types)
            {
                if (type.Name!=null && type.Name != "None")
                {
                    typesDic.Add(Convert.ToInt32(type.SubmitterActionRequiredTypeID), type.Name.ToString());
                }
            }

            return PartialView("JsonResult", typesDic.ToList()); 
        }
```

Ajax:

```
var submitterActionRequired = $("#submitterActionRequired").kendoDropDownList({
        optionLabel: "Select User Assignee...",
        dataTextField: "Value",
        dataValueField: "Key",
        height: 310,
        Width: "900px",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Submission/SubmitterActionTypes",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                            id: EntityOrganizationID
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            // notify the data source that the request succeeded
                            options.success(result);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            // notify the data source that the request failed
                            options.error(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the return type of the actionResult should be like this:

return Json(assignes)

The PartailView in this Context doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this approach but still no result in dropdown. I noticed changing action to JsonResult and returning JAson(assignees), call back does not work at all -- means once I click the drop down it does not go to Action. Here is the code I tried public JsonResult AssigneesForSubmission(int? id, bool? allowUnclaimed)
        {... return Json(assignees); }

Comment: Any other idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: If the call doesn't go the action, that mean, you miss something like, check the controllername in url if it's SubmissionController, or if the type of the action (Get or Post).

Comment: There are a special compatible returning object from Kendo in such scenario like returning a DataSourceRequest, give it a try public ActionResult AssigneesForSubmission([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int? id, bool? allowUnclaimed)
        {
            var wfs = DIResolver.GetConcreteInstanceOf<IWorkflowService>();
            var assignees = wfs.GetWorkflowAssigneeList(id.GetValueOrDefault(), UserContext.UserID, allowUnclaimed.GetValueOrDefault());
            return Json(assignees.ToDataSourceRequest(request));
        }

Comment: I tried with you code, but it did not work. Please ignore my earlier comment if it's confusing you. Kendo is not going to return anything here, Actually at onload we are trying to bind the data to dropdown list which is a Kendo. That approach mentioned above is working fine for another drop down but it does not work particularly this one. Is this because of the way we are returning the list?

Comment: I've updated code and description. Looks like I could streamline the issue. It's actually working with a simple dictionary and when I populate sample data in it. But when I populate real data then it's not showing result. This has probably nothing to do with Kendo but the data binding in MVC Action.